# How to import the jenkins-api in Groovy?

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, dependency-management, groovy-grape

I have a small groovy script that I want to edit and I have issues with the dependency management in Groovy. I am new to groovy and sorry in advance if this question is kinda studip / easy to answer.
I use `IntelliJ` as IDEA.

```
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.167', scope='provided')
//import jenkins...

def call()
{
    Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(currentBuild.fullProjectName).getBuilds().each{ build ->

        if (currentBuild.number > build.number && exec != null)
        {
           build.rawBuild.doKill()
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use the [jenkins-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/jenkins-core/1.414) dependency to get the autocomple of the code, documentation etc. etc. for the code but it simply does not work. I also tried the maven dependency in the `pom` it does work neither.

So now to my question: How do I import the dependency of Jenkins correctly in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this dependency from jenkins-ci maven repo:

```
@GrabResolver(name='jenkins', root='http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.167')
```

Comment: I get the following error. Findbugs in the release maybe? @Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.9'): 0 jars Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1!jsr305.jar] 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1

Comment: I am using Java 11 and Groovy 3.0.0-alpha4

Comment: Findbugs hasn't been updated in a few years. Looks like it doesn't work on JDK 11

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not able to get a working setup. Do you know which Java JDK works with the jenkins-ci maven repo?

Comment: JDK 8. Here you can find more detailed info: https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/

Comment: It finally worked, thanks god! I had to delete the .groovy and .m2 folder and do the Grab again. Thanks for your help!