# What is a Jenkins Stage in terms of Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to figure out what is a stage in terms of Grooy syntax. What is that syntax:

```
stage 'stage 1'
    statement 1
    statement 2
    statement n

stage 'stage 2'
    statement 1
    statement 2
    statement n
```

or I think this is the newer way to create a stage?

```
stage ('stage'){
    statement 1
    statement 2
    statement n
}
```

The first code block almost looks like [labeled statements](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements) but it's missing the colon after the name.

If I wanted to do something like this in Groovy, how would I do it?

I'm a Jenkins and Groovy noob.

[Attempt to clarify my question]
I wanted to know what a stage construct is in terms of Groovy code.

For example, if I asked what is this block of Groovy code

```
def somefnc(){
   ..statements
}
```

Someone would say "That is how you define a function in Groovy, you use the keyword `def` give the function a name..."

My question is what is this

```
stage ('stage'){
    statement 1
    statement 2
    statement n
}
```

Is this part of the Groovy language? What is it called? My understanding is that a Jenkins file is Groovy code. So is there some Jenkins preprocessor running? Or is the above valid Groovy and I can use it some how in my plain Groovy? I don't mean "`stage`", can I define whatever that is and have a

```
steve('some arguments'){
    statments...
}
```

Comment: Your second example is the proper syntax for a stage, more information here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline

Comment: To answer the later part of your question, stage is not Groovy, it is Jenkins DSL (Domain Specific Language) -- you cannot write a 'plain' Groovy class and use stage. More info here:

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the last argument of a function is of type `Closure` you can add the closure after the arguments
so:

```
def stage(String name, Closure body) {
        println "stage(${name})"
        body.call()
    }
```

can be called like this:

```
stage("stage 1"){
   println "inside stage 1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is the almost correct syntax but missing a `steps{}-block`. The official [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stages) is a great help regarding syntaxes and other questions.

So regarding your example this would be the 100% correct syntax if you want to use a stage in a declarative pipeline (I think this is what you referd as 'newer way', the 'old way' would be a scripted pipeline).

```
stage ('stage'){
    steps {
       statement 1
       statement 2
       statement n
   }
}
```

Comment: What are those blocks in terms of Groovy? Is `stage` an extension to Groovy? It's not a function or a labeled block...so what is it?

Comment: I am not sure if I would count this purely to Groovy. Rather I would say it is a syntax for a Jenkinsfile that can be imported by using the Jenkins Groovy API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016767/how-to-import-the-jenkins-api-in-groovy. This also allows you syntax highliting etc.

Comment: Then how would you do this in Groovy?

Comment: You can't simply write stage and execute it. You need to write a Jenkinsfile (which includes the stages, the overall pipeline) and this has to be executed by an instance of Jenkins. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I'll add more to my question.

Comment: Updated. Hope that clears up what I'm getting at. I did try to look at the underlying Java source, and it looks like they may have added to the Groovy language?