# Is a Jenkinsfile in pure Groovy? What Groovy language construct is used in `steps` in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

**What Groovy language construct, syntax or control structure is used in the following code fragment in a Jenkinsfile?**

```
stage('Stage 1') {
    steps {
        // One or more steps
    }
}
```

i.e. What are blocks in Jenkinsfile, in terms of pure Groovy language?

what is 'steps'? or `stage`?
Is it calling a function? or definition? or a function call with anonymous (lambda) argument?

Inherent in this question is another question:

Question 2:

**Is a Jenkinsfile, a code fragment in groovy language?**

In other words, 1. Does a Jenkinsfile follow all syntax and control structures of pure Groovy? (perhaps by an implicit library import-ed or #include d silently in beginning),

As opposed to being a DSL: 2. Jenkinsfile being almost a groovy source file augmented with new Jenkins-specific constructs not originally in Groovy, e.g. Jenkins using a preprocessing.

Which of the above two hold?

**Related:**

- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/
- https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#directive-generator
- [What is a Jenkins Stage in terms of Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279390/what-is-a-jenkins-stage-in-terms-of-groovy) (despite similar title, the ask is different. The related comments are inconclusive).

Comment: Related question: "What is a Jenkins Stage in terms of Groovy?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279390/what-is-a-jenkins-stage-in-terms-of-groovy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Jenkins (or Gradle) 2 main features are used:

1. Groovy (java) idiomatic structures like loops, switches, chain of command etc
2. DSLBuilder facility based on `Closure`s to allow for nesting and invoking of domain-specific methods as they were a part of Groovy itself.

So, if you write something like

```
stage('Stage 1') {
    steps {
        // One or more steps
    }
}
```

it translates internaly to roughly:

```
jenkinsContext.stage('Stage 1') {
    jenkinsContext.steps {
        // One or more steps
    }
}
```

so it is way clearer to write and read. Here the Closures - the `{...}` blocks - represent nesting or grouping of your code.

In this block you can also see Groovy's way of calling methods where the last argument is a Closure. The code above could be rewritten as:

```
jenkinsContext.stage 'Stage 1', { // here no brackets around args
    jenkinsContext.steps( { // here with normal java-style brackets
        // One or more steps
    } )
}
```

In jenkins you can mix and match DSL calls with Groovy structures:

```
[ 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2' ].each{
  stage( it ) {}
}
```

or even have your DSL names generated dynamically:

```
[ 'Stage 1':'stage', 'step 2':'steps' ].each{ value, name ->
  "$name"( value ) {}
}
```

would create the DSL (as example ONLY!):

```
  stage( 'Stage 1') {}
  steps( 'Step 2' ) {}
```

So, Jenkins pipeline syntax is Groovy + Jenkins DSL

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the well written answer.

Comment: So `DSLBuilder` is something (aa utility) outside the Groovy's language and SDK, and is Jenkins-specific. It is a source preprocessor that translates (transforms) a semi-Groovy (but not strictly Groovy) source file into pure Groovy. It modifies the code in the `Jenkinsfile`  in various ways such as adding prefixes, imports certain libraries in beginning of the source file, etc. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: Not quite. There's no semi-Groovy here. The pipeline scripts are pure Groovy and they are fed to Groovy-based Jenkins' DSL builder, and get executed. Important point here, is that the script is not precompiled (like java class would) because of code like `steps{}` which is not provided in Groovy SDK.

Comment: Groovy is flexible about code which can not be compiled straight away, hence you can create a script of arbitrary code which will work in some specific context later on

Comment: I thought I had the answer, but now it seems I know nothing in terms of answer to the question: "Is a Jenkinsfile in pure Groovy?".

Comment: define "pure groovy"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's primarily Groovy, so if you're looking for simply syntax highligting adding something like the following does the job.

`<!-- language: lang-groovy -->`

There are caveats however documented in the online docs, so maybe this implies it's not written in pure groovy but some specialized/constrained form of it?

> The basic statements and expressions which are valid in Declarative Pipeline follow the same rules as Groovy’s syntax with the following **exceptions**:
>
> - The top-level of the Pipeline must be a block, specifically: pipeline { }.
> - No semicolons as statement separators. Each statement has to be on its own line.
> - Blocks must only consist of Sections, Directives, Steps, or assignment statements.
> - A property reference statement is treated as a no-argument method invocation. So, for example, input is treated as input().
>
> https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline