# How to identify methods on Jenkins objects?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Suppose, I run one Jenkins job from another like -

```
def result = build job: 'ChildJob', parameters: []
println result.getRawBuild().getLog()
```

Here on `result` object, we can see `getRawBuild()` method can be invoked. But when write code in pipeline we cannot see auto-population of method. In this case, how to identify what are methods available on Jenkins objects? Which document will help to get all those details?

Comment: pick a IDE like IntelliJ and import the Jenkins API (for autocomplete) this will make development a lot easier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016767/how-to-import-the-jenkins-api-in-groovy